# Selenium Python exception errors while trying to change frame

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, error-handling

I wasn't able to close the modal dialog box. I checked further and had  to change frames to be
able to close the appearing modal box. But the number of errors are rising day by day as I make
changes to the code. Could anyone please tell me how to access and close the box and then return to the normal page??
Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import openpyxl
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

path="C://Users/manav/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/tabledel.xlsx"
workbk=openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet=workbk.active

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\manav\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.get("https://www.edelweiss.in/market/nse-option-chain/")
time.sleep(1)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tableContent']/table[2]/tfoot/tr/td[8]/a").click()
time.sleep(2)

rows=len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='tableContent']/table[1]/tbody/tr"))
print(rows)

cols=len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='tableContent']/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td"))
print(cols)
time.sleep(2)

driver.switch_to.frame("wiz-iframe-intent")  #intentPreview
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentDiv']/div/div/p/a/span").click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.switch_to.default_content()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentDiv']/div/div/p/a/span").click()
time.sleep(1)

for r in range(1,rows+1):
    for c in range(1,cols+1):
        val=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*      #continoued on same line
        [@id='tableContent']/table[1]/tbody/tr["+str(r)+"]/td["+str(c)+"]").text    
        sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value = val
        print(val,end='    |    ')
    print()

workbk.save(path)
```

Comment: Please share what error you got with above code ??

Comment: It says there's no other frame. I just want to access the modal box and close it.